# Optimal Buffer Stream write process

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

We have our own data streaming algorithm that include some metadata+records+fields values.

Currently we use a TStream and write to add values to the stream.
Now I'm wondering if this time cosuming operation could be made faster by using some technic.

**Edit:** We are only appending data to the end, not moving or seeking.

Some things I was thinking of are:

- Not use Streams buf some large memory allocated buffer to copy data to, the problem is if we go beyond the buffer size, then we have to relocate to some new memory space.
- Use a Stream prefilled with #0s to some size and then start adding values. The rationale is that Tstream have to allocate it's own buffer every time I do a write (I don't know how it really works, just wondering...)

We are adding strings to the TStream and binary data in the form #0#0#0#1 for example.

The data is then transfered via TCP, so it's not about write to a File.

So what is the best method for this?

Comment: You are talking about memory streams right?

Comment: If the amount of data is big(say more than 200MB), then I recommend a TFileStream, otherwise TMemoryStream would be the fastest and easiest way IMHO. If you choose to use TFile|MemoryStream and you need to keep information like(record count, etc.), add a header at the beginning of the Stream and after every update reset cursor position to the beginning, read and override header the Stream.Position := Stream.Size; <- bam you are at the end of the stream, continue with appending data. If there's any chance of record deletion, then each record needs a header that contains a flag(Deleted: Boolean)

Comment: @Dorin: We are using for sending using sockets, so TFileStream seems not to be an option. The problem is not How to do it using stream+write, we are already using that, the question is If there is some way to do it faster.

Comment: Socket.Send(AMemoryStream.Memory^, AMemoryStream.Size) (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overwrite TMemoryStream and remove the restriction of Size and Capacity. And do not call TMemoryStream.Clear but call TMemoryStream.SetSize(0)

```
type
  TMemoryStreamEx = class(TMemoryStream)
  public
    procedure SetSize(NewSize: Longint); override;
    property Capacity;
  end;

implementation

{ TMemoryStreamEx }

procedure TMemoryStreamEx.SetSize(NewSize: Integer);
var
  OldPosition: Longint;
begin
  if NewSize > Capacity then
    inherited SetSize(NewSize)
  else
  begin
    OldPosition := Position;
    SetPointer(Memory, NewSize);
    if OldPosition > NewSize then
      Seek(0, soFromEnd);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

First, you are assuming the `TStream` is the bottleneck.  You need to profile your code, such as with AQTime, to determine where the bottleneck really is.  Don't make assumptions.

Second, what type of `TStream` are you actually using?  `TMemoryStream`?  `TFileStream`?  Something else?  Different stream types handle memory differently.  TMemoryStream allocates a memory buffer and grows it by a pre-set amount of bytes whenever the buffer fills up.  `TFileStream`, on the other hand, doesn't use any memory at all, it just writes directly to the file and lets the OS handle any buffering.

Regardless of which type of stream you use, one thing you could try is implement your own custom `TStream` class that has an internal fixed-size buffer and a pointer to your real destination `TStream` object.  You can then pass an instance of your custom class to your algorithm.  Have your class override the `TStream::Write()` method to copy the input data into its buffer until it fills up, then you can `Write()` the buffer to the destination `TStream` and clear the buffer.  Your algorithm will never know the difference.  Both `TMemoryStream` and `TFileStream` would benefit from the extra buffering - fewer larger writes means more efficient memory allocations and file I/O.  For example:

```
type
  TMyBufferedStreamWriter = class(TStream)
  private
    fDest: TStream;
    fBuffer: array[0..4095] of Byte;
    fOffset: Cardinal;
  public
    constructor Create(ADest: TStream);
    function Read(var Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint; override;
    function Write(const Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint; override;
    procedure FlushBuffer;
  end;
```

.

```
uses
  RTLConsts;

constructor TMyBufferedStreamWriter.Create(ADest: TStream);
begin
  fDest := ADest;
end;

function TMyBufferedStreamWriter.Read(var Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint;
begin
  Result := 0;
end;

function TMyBufferedStreamWriter.Write(const Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint;
var
  pBuffer: PByte;
  Num: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := 0;
  pBuffer := PByte(@Buffer);
  while Count > 0 do
  begin
    Num := Min(SizeOf(fBuffer) - fOffset, Cardinal(Count));
    if Num = 0 then FlushBuffer;
    Move(pBuffer^, fBuffer[fOffset], Num);
    Inc(fOffset, Num);
    Inc(pBuffer, Num);
    Dec(Count, Num);
    Inc(Result, Num);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyBufferedStreamWriter.FlushBuffer;
var
  Idx: Cardinal;
  Written: Longint;
begin
  if fOffset = 0 then Exit;
  Idx := 0;
  repeat
    Written := fDest.Write(fBuffer[Idx], fOffset - Idx);
    if Written < 1 then raise EWriteError.CreateRes(@SWriteError);
    Inc(Idx, Written);
  until Idx = fOffset;
  fOffset := 0;
end;
```

.

```
Writer := TMyBufferedStreamWriter.Create(RealStreamHere);
try
  ... write data to Writer normally as needed...
  Writer.FlushBuffer;
finally
  Writer.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Use a profiler to see where it is actually slow.
2. If it is indeed because of multiple reallocation to increase the size of the stream, you can avoid that by setting the `Size` property to a big enough amount upfront.
3. The only case where using a memory buffer could make an obvious difference is if you're using FileStreams, all other useable streams are already doing this for you.

Comment: Reading the documentation (Delphi 7) only for TStringStream the Size property could be set, we can use this. We also should explore the Profiler route (never used)

Comment: @DanielLuyo, I just looked the D7 source and TStream has a public Size property that whatever descendent can use (read or write).