# Is there a way to speed up TStreamWriter::WriteLine ()?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I am using C++ Builder Tokyo 10.2.2. I have a project that involves writing files that are too large for TStringList (it causes memory errors).

Therefore, I created an alternate save system that used TStreamWriter. This works well, except for one small problem. It seems that TStreamWriter's WriteLine () is very slow compared to TStringList's Add ().

Here is code that compares the two.

```
TStopwatch sw = TStopwatch::StartNew ();

TStreamWriter* writer = new TStreamWriter (sFileName, false, TEncoding::UTF8, 1024);
for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
    writer->WriteLine (i);
delete writer;

sw.Stop ();
TTimeSpan ts = sw.Elapsed;
String s = String (ts.TotalMilliseconds) + " Milliseconds";

TStopwatch sw2 = TStopwatch::StartNew ();

TStringList* list = new TStringList ();
for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
    list->Add (i);
list->SaveToFile (sFileName);
delete list;

sw2.Stop ();
TTimeSpan ts2 = sw2.Elapsed;
String s2 = String (ts2.TotalMilliseconds) + " Milliseconds";
```

The most recent value for ts (using TStreamWriter) on my test system is 2748. The most recent value for ts2 (using TStringList) is 522. So, TStreamWriter is taking more than 5 times longer to achieve the same functionality.

Am I missing something with TStreamWriter that could significantly increase its speed?

Comment: Use a buffered stream. See this answer, for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930552/optimal-buffer-stream-write-process

Comment: @Alexandre: note that `TStreamWriter` is already buffered internally, and in this example will be flushing to file in blocks of 1024 bytes.

Comment: `TStrings.Add()` adds a `string` as-is to the end of the list. It won't allocate any new memory if it doesn't exceed the current `Capacity`. `TStrings.SaveTo...()` allocates a single `string` to hold the entire list, including line breaks, then converts that `string` to a byte array and writes it to the output. `TStreamWriter.WriteLine(Integer)` converts the `Integer` to a `string`, appends a line break to it, converts it to a byte array, and writes it to the internal buffer, flushing to the output if needed. So yes, your `WriteLine()` loop is doing a LOT more work than your `Add()` loop.

Comment: These tasks could all be done without any heap allocation if the code was well optimised. Since you are using C++ surely you can use the STL, or is the Emba implementation no good?

Comment: @RemyLebeau any stream writer 5x slower than TStrings (which is not exactly known for exceptional performance) just can't be well implemented, doesn't matter if a buffer is used internally. There are plenty of buffered TStream descendants that are at least 2-3x faster than TStrings, your own implementation included. He doesn't need to use TStreamWriter. Use a TStream

Comment: @Alexandre: The `TStringList` example can still outperform a buffered stream. I just did a test using the code in this question, where `TStreamWriter` by itself took 8805ms, `TStringList` took 227ms, [`TMyBufferedStreamWriter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9932487/65863) using a `TFileStream` took 457ms, and `TStreamWriter` using `TMyBufferedStreamWriter` with a `TFileStream` took 412ms

Comment: @RemyLebeau I haven't actually tested your class mentioned in my first comment. But I've just tested my own implementation of TBufferedFileStream. The results are: TStringList (msec) : 208
TBufferedFileStream (msec) : 57, which confirms what I've said that not TStringList nor TStreamWriter are known for their performance

Comment: @Alexandre I wonder what your own implementation of `TBufferedFileStream` looks like including your timing code?

Comment: @TomBrunberg My code is exactly like the one you see in the original question, although I prefer to use Delphi. My buffered stream descends from THandleStream and overrides Read, Write and Seek methods. It uses an internal buffer (array of byte allocated in the constructor. I use 8 Kb because it presented best results in my real test scenario). Buffer is used until full. Then it is flushed to the actual stream calling the inherited Write() method.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Alexandre but I asked for your implementation because I was hoping to confirm your claim of 57ms vs 208ms. But oh well, it's not really important.

Comment: @TomBrunberg you are basically saying that "if you don't show me the code it is probably a lie" ;-) The code is proprietary so I cannot publish it. I gave you all directions except the code. It is not hard to implement it, knowing exactly what I said above.

Comment: No @Alexandre, that is not at all what I'm saying, and I do understand and accept that your code is proprietary. For me, what you said, is simply just an unconfirmed claim, not really important.

Comment: @Alexandre: stream writers write per line, and even if they are buffered, that means many more writes than one. TStringList.SaveToStream only does one physical write. Depending on the hardware (HDD or SDD), the stringlist can be much faster.

Comment: @Alexandre: I meant SSD, of course.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. This is the solution I have implemented. I used TStringStream, with the WriteString () function in particular, with a helper function to automatically append end of line ('\n') to each string written. The time seems comparable to the TStringList solution, but without the memory limits that come with TStringList.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis all you said is correct, however I think TStringList was not designed for this task. It is not the correct mechanism to save to a file. Each element in a TStringList occupies an additional 16 bytes (12 for the string + 4 for the object pointer even if NIL). If you need to write one bazzilion elements, it is just a waste of memory. Besides that, writing to a TStringList is a waste of processor cycles, compared to writing to a pre allocated memory buffer.

Comment: @Alexandre: Obviously TStringList caused memory problems, but the fact remains it is much faster when writing to a file than I don't know how many repeats of TSreamWriter.WriteLine, simply because of the reduced I/O. Repeated writes to a file are slower than one single large write.